# How can I flush all loggers in a dotnet core appliation just before doing a Environment.Exit()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Basically I have the old known issue of an application crashing and having no debug logs, because the application terminated before it could write the logs.

A classic approach is to catch all Exceptions in main and to flush all log buffers in the exception block. Furthermore adding a sleep to reduce the restart speed and allow the buffers to finish the flush.

I use serilog, and I found this ticket: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/1111

It suggests to do as I suggested (code pasted below), but I am uncertain it will close and flush all loggers and not just the main logger.

1. Will I have to flush more loggers, to get all logs?
2. This example assumes, that ConfigureLogging() sets up the logger, but in a real asp .netcore main you usually don't have the logger set up, how do I get to do that?

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    ConfigureLogging(); // set up Serilog

    try
    {
        Log.Logger.Information("Custom.API Server is starting.");
        var webHost = BuildWebHost(args);
        webHost.Run();

        Log.Logger.Information("Custom.API Server is starting.");
        return 0;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly.");
        return 1;
    }
    finally
    {
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
        Thread.Sleep(2000); // give serilog / seq time to flush the messages
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean that the logs were not written after you call **CloseAndFlush**? What's kind of sink are you using? And can you confirm that the application crash was caused by your own code and the exception already was caught by the code?

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT no that's all peripheral. I'm running a dotnet core console app, that is not using ASP.net core. The issue is that in main you don't have an instance of the logger itself and thus cannot flush it explicitly.