# How to prevent .net 6 generic hosted console apps logging queue from being shutdown on application stop?

Tags: c#, .net-core, logging, ihostedservice

I'm currently working on a small demo project for a dotnet console application using the generic hosting for logging and configuration. In the context of writing this demo / proof of concept app I ran into the problem, that the log messages to the console stopped being written, but the program itself finished his work without a problem.

The console app here should do batch processing and is not intended as a long running service. We intend to find out if (and how) the items can be processed in a parallel manner. Therefore we created this demo program. In this demo program, we intentionally decided **NOT** to use async calls. First, to make it as linear as possible and, second, to make it as understandable as possible. In upcomming iterations we will add / remove such features, depending on the paths we explore and the runtime behaviour.

It's my first experience with the generic hosting in dotnet 6(+). I would like to benefit from the out of the box features like DI, configuration and logging.

Now my questions:

- For a batch processing console application in dotnet: is the generic hosting environment the right approach?
- For batch processing is `IHostedService` the right way? Should I rather use `BackgroundService`?
- Ideally: How do I control the application so it waits for the `console logger queue` to finish its job?
- Here's desperate me asking: What am I doing wrong? Which detail do I miss?

Here's the very simplified setup:

#### Program.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

using var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.ClearProviders();
        logging.AddConsole();
    })
    .ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    })
    .Build();

host.Start();
// host.Run(); // could be used instead of host.Start();
```

#### Worker.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

internal class Worker : IHostedService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _log;
    private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _appLifetime;

    public Worker2(ILogger<Worker> log,
        IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime
    ) => (_log, _appLifetime) = (log, appLifetime);

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _log.LogInformation("now load a list of item numbers");
        var itemNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000);

        foreach (var itemNumber in itemNumbers)
        {
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                break;
            _log.LogInformation("processing item nr {itemNumber}", itemNumber);
        }

        _log.LogInformation("I'm done here. good bye!");

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

#### example output to console

```
info: Worker2[0]
      now load a list of item numbers
info: Worker2[0]
      processing item nr 1
info: Worker2[0]
      processing item nr 2
info: Worker2[0]
      processing item nr 3
...
info: Worker2[0]
      processing item nr 22
info: Worker2[0]
      processing item nr 23
info: Worker2[0]
      processing item nr 24

Process finished with exit code 0.
```

When debugging this simple app, it shows, that its actually running through all 1000 items and it's also logging the last message ("I'm done here. good bye!"). Unfortunately, the logs from item nr. 25 and up are never written to the console.

What I found out:

- The application creates two main threads: one for the `worker` and one for the `console logger queue`.
- I have no control over the `console logger queue` thread
- If I shutdown the `worker` (or it finishes) it shuts down the application and the application does not wait for the `console logger queue` (and therefore kills it).
- Using `BackgroundService` gives me the same result.
- Using `host.Run()` instead of `host.Start()` did work, although I had to manually stop the application, which is also not what I want. When it's done with its work, it should terminate.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap the app.Start in a try/catch/finally ... and depending on whether you're using something like Serilog ... call Log.CloseAndFlush() in the finally.

Similar question here: [How can I flush all loggers in a dotnet core appliation just before doing a Environment.Exit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62391104/how-can-i-flush-all-loggers-in-a-dotnet-core-appliation-just-before-doing-a-envi)

Comment: Hey Scott, many thanks for this quick answer. I added Serilog and implemented the change. This solves the main problem with the cutting off the logs. I wanted to implement it without a third party lib (like Serilog). Do you know if this is possible with pure 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging'? I haven't found anything in that direction yet. A question for **your opinion**: Is the generic host approach with IHostedService the right way for a batch processing app?

Comment: I've relied on Serilog for a number of years ... one of the few libraries that I truly trust.  As for generic host, sorry, I could not say. I mainly work with Blazor apps, but the one console app I've updated from .NET Framework to Core, is a self contained process, that does not use a "host" process at all. I just create an instance of ServiceCollection, configure and instantiate the services that app requires.